# What do I need to do when replacing my wireless router?

Tags: router, installation, wireless-router

I currently have a very old wireless router that has been giving out on me lately. If I were to replace it with a newer and better one, what will I need to do in order to set it up? Besides the obvious plugging it into my modem.

How should I install it with my modem? What is involved with setting up a new router? Will my ISP have to do anything?

What router would you recommend?

Comment: What sort of internet and modem do you have?

Comment: It's a Netgear that looks almost exactly like this model: http://www.netgear.com/products/home/wirelessouters/simplesharing/WGR614.aspx

Comment: Actually I think it's this exact model: http://www.walmart.com/ip/NETGEAR-WGR614-Wireless-G-54Mbps-Broadband-Router/2304416

Answer (score 1):

If you have a seporate modem, there shouldn't be anything complicated you need to do.

One basic thing to make the transition as painless as possible would be to plug it in via ethernet to a machine and input the exact same wireless SSID, passkey and security method and also the same local IP settings.

If you do the above, it should be as simple as unplugging one and plugging in the other.

Comment: @wil - he may have a slight complication if he is using DSL with PPPOE settings in the router itself (and he's not aware of it).

Comment: @Wil, "plug it in via ethernet to a machine and input the exact same wireless SSID, passkey and security method and also the same local IP settings." How do I do this? I'm not very adept with networking.

Comment: @Erich - He would need to know the model of the old router to give specific directions, but most routers have a config page you access by going to the ip of the router in a browser window (normally http://192.168.1.1).  It requires a password, but you can check your settings from  there.

Comment: @JNK, It is this one: http://www.walmart.com/ip/NETGEAR-WGR614-Wireless-G-54Mbps-Broadband-Router/2304416

Comment: Depending on the age of his current router his encryption protocol may change. I had two older wireless cards that were not able to do WPA2.

Comment: @Beaner, all should be backward compatible, I said select the same security method so that he can ensure compatibility with all devices that currently work.

Comment: @Erich Wahl - You need to go to the config page as Jnk said, usually it should either be at http://192.168.0.1 or http://192.168.1.1 ... the instructions will most likely be on the bottom of the router.

Comment: Ummm, if possible you should think of this as an opportunity to try to update to the latest security protocols - change the SSID to something else than default, use WPA2 with a decent key, maybe disable WEP.  Also if you are running 802.11b, maybe update to G or N...

Comment: @blackbeagle - great suggestions.